# input type = number в Mozila

Tags: reactjs, input

В Google Chrome input при `type = "number"` ввод букв и символов автоматически контроллируется, однако в Mozila FireFox  даже задав тип `number` ввод букв и символов позволяется, хоть и при `submit`e выводится предупреждение, как сделать так чтобы в Mozila ввод в инпут был позволен только цифрам? (Использую React)

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать регулярное выражение, которое будет заменять нечисленные значения на пустые (функция handleInput):

```
import { useState } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");

  const handleInput = (event) => {
    const result = event.target.value.replace(/\D/g, "");

    setInput(result);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Ввод только для чисел"
        value={input}
        onChange={handleInput}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```